# Opening my iOS existing app from an email app which uses Gmail account doesn't work

Tags: ios, iphone, email, gmail, deep-linking

During the signup process, the user receives an email with "Activate Account" button and I want to able to open my existing app when this button is pressed.

I don't need to be redirected to AppStore.

I don't want to use branch.io! There are similar questions on stackoverflow, but all the responses has reference to branch.io or they are too old to be valid.

I added deep linking file on the website and I added the associated domain and `application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool` method in AppDelegate, in Xcode.

The button inside the email works if I am logged in in Safari and I don't use a native email app, but I need to be able to open the app from the email app.
Is there any chance to be able to do that?

**Edit** : The app is opened from the email app, unless if I use Gmail. My Mail app used Gmail as Default Account (Go to Settings -> Mail -> Default Accounts). The issue is available only for Gmail client.

Comment: [custom url scheme](https://coderwall.com/p/mtjaeq/ios-custom-url-scheme) could be used to open the app. But I don't think the link would work if the app wasn't installed. Not sure how to get around that

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it. The app is already installed.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you'd want to use [Universal App Links](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html). It allows you to have a normal url to your domain open in your app. If the user doesn't have the app installed, it will open the URL in safari.

Comment: I already did it. I have added on website the *apple-app-site-association* file with my bundle Id and App Team prefix.

Comment: Did you add the entitlement so your app can know what universal app domains it can handle?

Comment: I edited my question, the problem was reduces at Gmail account.